# Help guide "What topics can I ask about here?" links need to be updated

Tags: support, status-completed

The help guide for [What topics can I ask about here?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have a handful of links under the section "*What about other questions regarding anime and manga?*" that redirect to `meta.anime.stackexchange.com` rather than `anime.meta.stackexchange.com`. Since `meta.anime.stackexchange.com` [does not support HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299087/201625) (and the auto-redirect logic doesn't seem to be working for these urls), the browser displays the message:

> Your connection is not private

Please update the help guide so that the links properly redirect to `anime.meta.stackexchange.com`.